# DAX Current Unit Price by Item Based on Date Range

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a data model with a fact table called `PriceList` and three related dimension tables, Date, `CustomerPriceGroup`, and Item. The key columns of these tables are below.

**PriceList**

```
[CustomerPriceGroupID   ItemID  StartDateID EndDateID   UnitPrice   StartingDate    EndingDate
83                  14837   20130529    20130627    96.48           5/29/2013   6/27/2013
76                  14837   20130529    20130627    97.92           5/29/2013   6/27/2013
76                  14837   20160228    20160810    113.76          2/28/2016   8/10/2016
83                  14837   20160228    20160810    112.32          2/28/2016   8/10/2016][1]


**Date (sample data but dates range from 1/1/2010 to 12/31/2025)**

[DateID         Date
20130102    1/2/2013
20130103    1/3/2013
20130104    1/4/2013
20130105    1/5/2013
20130106    1/6/2013
20130107    1/7/2013
20130108    1/8/2013
20130109    1/9/2013][2]


**CustomerPriceGroup**

[CustomerPriceGroupID   Code
83                  TL
76                  LTL
20                  PL06
9                   PL01][3]


**Item**

[ItemID No
14837   F100690
14838   F100700
14839   F100710
14840   F100720][4]
```

What I would like to do is have a date slicer, either set as Between or Dropdown, so whether I select a range of dates or a single date, I'm returned the latest Unit Price for a given item in a given price group.

Using the PriceList fact table above, my expectation is that if I selected with my Date[Date] slicer dates between 6/1/2013 and 6/15/2013, I could product the following table:

```
CustomerPriceGroupID    ItemID    UnitPrice
76                      14837     97.92

Or selecting a single dropdown date for 7/1/2016, produce:

CustomerPriceGroupID    ItemID    UnitPrice
76                      14837     113.76
```

I've tried a few different renditions but I'm not getting there. Any thoughts?

```
Unit Price = 

VAR MinDate = MIN('dim Date'[Date])
VAR MaxDate = MAX('dim Date'[Date])

VAR Result = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('fact PriceList'[UnitPrice]),
    'fact PriceList'[StartingDate] >= MinDate && 'fact PriceList'[EndingDate] <= MaxDate
)

RETURN Result
```

The PBIX Sample file:
https://file.io/hLRRqbLGCMmF

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `Dim Date` and `fact PriceList`? If so, add `REMOVEFILTERS('dim Date')` in your `CALCULATE`.

Comment: I've tried this but no luck

Comment: And what about with `ALL('dim Date')`? Are you getting nothing returned? What other relationships are there and which columns are you using in the table/matrix visual? Can you share a link to sample/mock-up PBIX.

Comment: Nothing is being returned, no. The only other relationship to this fact table is on dim Customer which is not being included in the table visual. The only columns on the table visual are 'dim CustomerPriceGroup'[Code], 'dim Item'[No] and [Unit Price]

Comment: Are all the dates proper Date fields? Maybe try it with `DateID` instead

Comment: I've added the sample file if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working in your file. You just need to decide on the logic of your range.

```
// the fact range has to be full INSIDE the slicer range
'fact'[SDate] >= MinDate && 'fact'[EDate] <= MaxDate


// the fact range OVERLAPS the slicer range
'fact'[SDate] <= MaxDate && 'fact'[EDate] >= MinDate
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work. I tried this in the file accessed here:
https://filebin.net/6yv1s155miiax1j9

Comment: See above (abbreviated to shorten to hopefully help compare the conditionals).